# Why is my validation method for zip codes not working correctly

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form that uses `asp:requiredvalidator` and some custom javascript to apply a red 1px border around any field that hasn't been correctly filled in.

This works perfectly, but now I want to be able to immediately remove the red border when the user correctly fills in the field.

To achieve this, I am using Jquery's `focusout()` method to compare the user input to a regular expression. So far I have this correctly working on every field (including email validation) except zip code. For some reason, all the validation methods I have written work perfectly except for zip code.

Here is a working email validation for example

```
        if (id == "email1" || id == "email2") {
            emailValue = e.target.value;
            if (validateEmail(emailValue)) {
                $("#" + id).removeClass("ErrorControl");
            }
            else {

            }
        }

        function validateEmail(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        }
```

This works perfectly and removes the red border as soon as the field losses focus and the email is valid.

But I cannot get my zip validator working, even though it works almost the exact same way.

Here is the non working zip example

```
            //Zip code also require special validation to confirm
            if (id == "zip") {
                zipValue = e.target.value;
                if (validateZip(zipValue)) {
                    $("#" + id).removeClass("ErrorControl")
                }
            }

        //Simple zip validator
        function validateZip(zip) {
            var re = /^[0-9]{5}$/;
            return re.test(zip);
        }
```

Unfortunately this still removes the red border, even when I enter just letters in it! Why is this happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/hhjvstp3/

I have given both email and zip a class of ErrorControl since I cannot run asp validators on jsfiddle. This works exactly like I am describing. Email validates well, zip code removes the border no matter what.

Comment: What's going on when you debug it?

Comment: You should share example of  your code including html in jsfiddle.

Comment: Missing semicolon at  end of line: `$("#" + id).removeClass("ErrorControl");`

Comment: your validateZip function seems to be working fine, bug might be somewhere else, provide the full code

Comment: I'm working on creating a fiddle that by default has th e css class and is removed with the javascript (since my asp:validators wont work and my form wont have any red border as a result) I'll update post as soon as i have it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhjvstp3/1/)

You can see which line removes the ErrorControl class from zip

```
 if (id == "firstname" || id == "lastname" || id == "address1" || id == "city" || id == "amount") { 
    //id == "zip" shouldn't be here
     if (e.target.value != "") {
          $("#" + id).removeClass("ErrorControl");
      }
 }
```

Comment: Wow. So dumb of me to miss that. Thank you!